# How can I get the length of a session in SQL given multiple timestamps?

Tags: sql, sql-server, time

I have a table in MS SQL Server in which I run the following query:

```
  SELECT Time, SessionId
  FROM dbName
  WHERE SessionId IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY Time, SessionId
```

This returns a set of timestamps associated with a SessionId, and of course, there are multiple SessionIds. My question is, how can I further refine this query to return the average length of a session? i.e. get earliest timestamp and latest timestamp, diff them, and return value in seconds or minutes, and do this per unique SessionId.

From this, I think I can get the longest session, the shortest session and the average length of a session.

The timestamp looks like this: 2014-08-19 18:20:28.4359918

Comment: Are you working on MySQL? SQL Server?...

Comment: What does `Time` represent? The beginning or the end of the session? How can you determine the length of a session when you are not capturing both?

Comment: Time represents the timestamp of when some activity was logged during a session, hence multiple timestamps for the same session. The earliest time implies start of session and latest time implies end of session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT N.SessionId
    ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(N.Time), MAX(N.Time)) AS [sessionLenght]
FROM dbName N
WHERE N.SessionId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY N.SessionId
ORDER BY N.SessionId
```

If you want seconds instead of minutes, you just need to change the datepart define in the `DATEDIFF` function. Here is the documentation: [DATEDIFF](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Helpful! How would you modify the query to sum all the sessions by user (and orderby by that sum, desc)?

Comment: @PakiPat Replace SessionId by User in the query and set the OrderBy clause as following: `ORDER BY DATEDIFF(...)`. Is it what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using MS SQL, I suggest using a common table expression for readability as shown below...

```
;WITH cte AS (
-- Show information per sesion id
SELECT SessionId, MIN(time) AS Start, MAX(time) AS finish, 
DATEDIFF(s, MIN(time), MAX(time)) AS Duration
FROM #dbName GROUP BY SessionId
)

-- Uncomment next line to show each session and its duration in seconds.
-- Or, uncomment the line after to show average duration of all sessions.
-- SELECT * FROM cte;
SELECT AVG(Duration) AS AverageDuration FROM cte
```